# How to keep business logic seperate within GWT Composites?

Tags: gwt

I'm currently building a GWT login screen and I managed to get a basic version of the login structure working.

I created the following pieces:

- An entry point class (actually it was given).
- A main application screen composite.
- A login-screen composite.

I have the following logic in my entry point method:

```
MyApplication mainWindow = null;
public void onModuleLoad() {
    LoginScreen loginScreen = new LoginScreen() {
        @Override
        public String onLogin(String username, String password) {
            boolean passwordWasOk = rpcCheckUsernamePassword(username,password); // mechanism not important for this question
            if (passwordWasOk) {
                RootPanel.get().remove(0);
                mainWindow = new MyApplication();
                // Using root layout panel as main window is a layout type composite
                RootLayoutPanel.get().add(mainWindow);
                return null;
            } else {
                return "password was incorrect";
            }
        }
    };
    RootPanel.get().add(loginScreen);
}
```

So, I created a method in the LoginScreen composite that is called when the user clicks the 'Sign-In' button. If the onLogin method fails its validation of the username and password, then a narrative can be returned to the login composite so that it can update the user. The login screen will stay on the screen until the user uses a correct username/password combination.

My question is, is this the correct way to use composites? Where should my login logic ideally reside. Is a better alternative to inject some sort of login handler object in the constructor of the composite or via a setter or is the method I used quite normal?

As I'm planning to write quite a lot of code, I want to get the coding style correct from the outset.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For complex projects you'd want to use the [Model-View-Presenter](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) (MVP) design pattern. It allows you to separate the rendering logic (views) from the business logic. To get you started, the official documentation has [two](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html) [articles](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2.html) about it plus there's *that* [presentation by Ray Ryan](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html) that started the whole GWT + MVP = <3 haze :) After that I'd recommend browsing through MVP related questions on SO and [GWT's Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I watched the presentation that you linked to. Its almost TOO dense with information, moving at breakneck speed. The MVP/GWT pattern does seem to apply in my case. Thanks.